# How to understand the macro of "page_align" in kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel

the codes is:

```
#define PAGE_SHIFT      12
#define PAGE_SIZE       (1UL << PAGE_SHIFT)
#define PAGE_MASK       (~(PAGE_SIZE-1))

#define PAGE_ALIGN(addr)        (((addr)+PAGE_SIZE-1)&PAGE_MASK)
```

I know this marco aligns
any address on the page boundary. 
**How to understand this implement**
？

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It rounds up an `addr` to the next multiple of 4096 (i.e. 2<sup>12</sup>), by adding 4095  (i.e. 2<sup>12</sup>-1) to it and clearing the lowest 12 bits